# Apply a runtime function only when the runtime input equals a named member in a set of types

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-hana

I have a hana tuple of types

```
auto mytypes =\
  bh::make_tuple(bh::type_c<T1>,
         bh::type_c<T2>,
         bh::type_c<T3>,
         bh::type_c<T4>);
```

Each of the `T` are simple C++ structs. They all have a member

```
static const std::string mtype
```

My function is currently

```
process(const std::string& intype)
{
  if (intype==T1::mtype)
     get<T1>();
  else if (intype==T2::mtype)
     get<T2>();
   ...
}
```

and I have a template function

```
template <typename T> T* get();
```

How do I run the function `get()` **only** on the type T where `T::mtype == intype` ?
The purpose is to determine which `Ti` type to select from the runtime value `intype`.
Instead of having explicit if statements for each possible type, i would like to generate that behaviour with something like hana::for_each, but only apply when the type matches

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between `process` and `get`. Like, how would `get` retrieve a parameter from `process`? Also, what do you mean by "run the function"? Who would be "running" it?

Answer (score 0):

With hana, you can access the type of a `type<T>` using the unary `+` operator:

```cpp
auto x = type_c<T>;
using TAlias = typename decltype(+x)::type; // = T
```

You can use that to access the static `::mtype` property inside your `hana::for_each` loop:

```cpp
void process(const std::string& intype) {
    bh::for_each(mytypes, [&intype](auto&& t) {
        using T = typename decltype(+t)::type;
        if (T::mtype == intype) {
            T* value = get<T>();
            /* do something with value... */
        }
    });
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/7zovnY